# Can Gitkraken mention conflicted files in commit message?

Tags: commit, gitkraken, merge-conflict

In Sourcetree, when merging results in conflicts, the conflicted files are automatically added to the commit message, like this

[image]

Is this also possible with Gitkraken?

Comment: Good question. Did you find a way?

Comment: Sadly, no answer